# Why do I have docker pushed denied after login with boto ecr client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have the following code:

```
token = boto3.Session().client('ecr').get_authorization_token()
token = token['authorizationData'][0]
username, password = b64decode(token['authorizationToken']).decode().split(':')
```

Here I see username=AWS and a password. If I use these credentials on command line with `docker login -u AWS -p xxx [SERVER]` I get "Login Succeeded" and I can then `docker push`.

However in the python docker SDK, I do:

```
docker_client = docker.from_env()
login_response = docker_client.login({
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'registry': token['proxyEndpoint'],
        })
```

with response:

```
{'IdentityToken': '', 'Status': 'Login Succeeded'}
```

but when I do then:

```
docker_client.images.push()
```

I receive an access denied error.

If I first log in with the CLI, then the python script works.

Comment: I have run into the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Not really at that time I eventually logged in with cli from time to time